# RxSwift for tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Tags: swift, tableview

I began studying swift and rxswift and I'm on the part of tableview

i have this code

```swift
private func setUpBindings() {
        table.register(UINib(nibName: "InjectablesTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: String(describing: InjectablesTableViewCell.self))
        table.rx.setDelegate(self).disposed(by: disposeBag)

        injectables.bind(to: table.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "InjectablesTableViewCell", cellType: InjectablesTableViewCell.self)) { (row, injectables, cell) in
            cell.cellInjectables = injectables
            }.disposed(by: disposeBag)

        viewModel
            .injectables
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .bind(to: self.injectables)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
```

which I understand that covers/replace the tableview data source function:

```swift
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int

tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

how can i do  the same or in a way of rxswift for the function of editing cells

```swift
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer way back, so just to share:

```
injectables.bind(to: table.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "InjectablesTableViewCell", cellType: InjectablesTableViewCell.self)) { (row, injectables, cell) in
        cell.cellInjectables = injectables
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```